# How to use props within the same component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking to make a component that is filled with tweets.

I am creating an array called "tweets" and I would like to access the array in the return(). I know about mapping, but is there a way to just display one on the page? I thought it would be like {this.props.name} or just {props.name} but it doesn't render anything to the page.

How can I reference the props to my page within the same component?

Tweets.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Tweets = (props) => { 
    const tweets = [
        {name: 'Name 1',
        tweet:'This is a tweet!'},

        {name:'Name 2',
        tweet:'This is another tweet'},

        {name:'Name 3',
        tweet:'This is yet another tweet!'},
        ]

        return (
            <section>
                <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
            </section>
        )
}


export default Tweets;
```

Comment: As pointed out below, function components don't have this.props. You've put the props parameter in the function definition, then ignored it. But the data isn't in props anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tweets are inside the component itself, they are not coming from props. So you can access a single value with something like this:

```
{tweets[0].name}
```

If you want to display them all, you can do something like this:

```
  return (
      <section>
        {
          tweets.map(({name, tweet}) => (
            <div>
              <h1>{name}</h1>
              <p>{tweet}</p>
            </div>
          ))
        }
          
      </section>
  )
```